# Visual Studio 2013 - Class Diagram strangeness

Tags: visual-studio-2013

VS2013 Premium update 3.  When I right click on a .cs and do View Class Diagram, VS seems to be putting all entities on 1 .cd file.  Even though they are in a different Namespace.

Is this standard behaviour, or is something stuffed in this solution?

[image]

Relevant section of .csproj

Source https://github.com/djhmateer/AltNetDI

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Example8.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Example7.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Example6.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Example5.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Example2.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Example6Mike.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Example1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="ClassDiagram1.cd" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Example1.cs

```
namespace AltNetDI1 {
class CompositionRoot {
    public static void EMain() {
        // Instantiating the objects we will need
        IReader reader = new TextFileReader();
        IWriter writer = new ConsoleWriter();

        // Pass objects to our Appliction via Dependency Injection
        IApplication application = new Application(reader, writer);
        application.Run();
    }
}
```

Example2.cs

```
namespace AltNetDI2 {
    class CompositionRoot {
        public static void EMain() {
            IReader reader = new TextFileReader();

            //IWriter writer = new ConsoleWriter();
            // Decorating ConsoleWriter with a WriterLogger
            IWriter writer = new WriterLogger(new ConsoleWriter());

            // Pass objects to our Appliction via Dependency Injection
            IApplication application = new Application(reader, writer);
            application.Run();
        }
    }
```